# Change Document/Template After Envelope Has Been Generated

Tags: docusignapi

I am playing with a sanbox account for docusign.  I have created a template in the sandbox website, and am using the API to generate envelopes using that template.

If I edit the document or template at the website after the email has been sent and viewed by signer 1 (but not yet signed), will it invalidate the envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not invalidate the envelope.  Once an envelope is sent it has all the information it needs to process towards completion, even if you modify or delete the template it was created from.  The template is simply used to help streamline the sending process and once the envelope is sent there is no attachment to it or anything like that.